# Files in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, file-exists

I'm currently tasked with reading some data that stored in a flat file into my database and run reports against it. The one problem I'm running into is checking to see if a file actually exists. Is there a simple function to check if the file exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just googling I found [this](http://www.sqldba.org/articles/36-check-if-file-exists-in-sql-server.aspx) at SQL DBA and [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1272) at MS SQL tips.

Comment: Hum... seems my google skills aren't working well today. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing ETL in a stored procedure?!! I don't think you should, just because you can.

I recommend you use use SSIS for this. Doing ETL in Stored Proc or TSQL is not a recommended practice, in fact, it is frequently used as an example of what not to do.

Comment: I am not, mainly because there is already a procedure that I can use to import files coded by someone else. I'm just checking to see if a file exists before sending it over to that procedure. However you've piqued my interest. Do you know of any good sources that I could learn to use SSIS from?

Comment: @Shaded I would start with SQL Server Integration Services Step By Step book from the Microsoft press

Comment: @Shaded check this out http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b1145e7a-a4e3-4d14-b1e7-d1d823b6a447&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Path varchar(128) ,
 @FileName varchar(128)
 SET @Path = 'C:\'
 SET @FileName = 'FILE_NAME.EXT'

DECLARE @objFSys int
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @File varchar(1000)

 SET @File = @Path + @FileName
 EXEC sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @objFSys out
 EXEC sp_OAMethod @objFSys, 'FileExists', @i out, @File
 IF @i = 1
  PRINT 'file exists'
 ELSE
  PRINT 'file does not exists'
 EXEC sp_OADestroy @objFSys
```

[This article](http://www.sqldba.org/articles/36-check-if-file-exists-in-sql-server.aspx) goes over this method and a couple others.